# Custom routing through global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a site hosted on the server and it has a sub domain.  In my Global.asax.cs I've the map route as below

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and when I access the site subdomain like mysite.mydomain.com , i want it to be redicted to a sub domain something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "mySiteController", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but I'm not able to achieve this. 
How do I conditionally route based on the url accessed, from the Global.asax.cs

Thanks in advance.

Tarak

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute( 
    "{Controller}.example.com", // Domain with parameters 
    "{action}/{id}",    // URL with parameters 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults 
))
```

For more information check out [ASP.NET MVC Domain Routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx) link

Comment: DomainRoute isn't a built in class, you'll need to implement that, too (the example is in the link)

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a custom route constraint for this scenario:

```
public class DomainRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
    string _host;

    public DomainRouteConstraint(string host) {
        _host = host;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, 
                          Route route, 
                          string parameterName,        
                          RouteValueDictionary values, 
                          RouteDirection routeDirection) {
        return _host.Equals(httpContext.Request.Url.Host,
                            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Then use the constraint in your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
    new { controller = "mySiteController", 
          action = "Index", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional}, // defaults
    new DomainRouteConstraint("mysite.mydomain.com")); // constraint
```

or (to use multiple constraints in one route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
    new { controller = "mySiteController", 
          action = "Index", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional}, // defaults
    new { ignored = DomainRouteConstraint("mysite.mydomain.com"), 
          /* add more constraints here ... */ }); // constraints
```